# QTranslator on default context menu for QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I have a problem with translation default context menu for QTextEdit, QPlainTextEdit and QTextBrowser in PyQt5 using qt_xx.qm from `site-packages/PyQt5/translations` folder. It works properly for QLineEdit for example (this is the same context menu). How to deal with it?

Code to reproduce a problem:

```py
# coding: utf-8

import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QLocale
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTranslator
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        widget = QWidget()

        lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        textEdit = QTextEdit()

        vbox = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        vbox.addWidget(lineEdit)
        vbox.addWidget(textEdit)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    locale = QLocale.system().name()

    qtTranslator = QTranslator()
    if qtTranslator.load('C:/Python33/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/translations/qt_' + locale):
        app.installTranslator(qtTranslator)

    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, I tried to solve the problem by modifying the standard context menu created by calling method `QTextEdit::createStandardContext`, and it did work.
Here is the code:

```
void CWQTextEdit::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *e)
{
    QMenu *menu = QTextEdit::createStandardContextMenu();
    if (menu == NULL)
        return QTextEdit::contextMenuEvent(e);

    QList<QAction*> actions = menu->actions();

    foreach (QAction *action, actions)
    {
       QString actionText = action->text();
       if (actionText.contains("Undo"))
       {
           actionText.replace("Undo", tr("Undo"));
           action->setText(actionText);
       }
       else if (actionText.contains("Redo"))
       {
           actionText.replace("Redo", tr("Redo"));
           action->setText(actionText);
       }
       else if (actionText.contains("Cu&t"))
       {
           actionText.replace("Cu&t", tr("Cut"));
           action->setText(actionText);
       }
       else if (actionText.contains("Copy"))
       {
           actionText.replace("Copy", tr("Copy"));
           action->setText(actionText);
       }
       else if (actionText.contains("Paste"))
       {
           actionText.replace("Paste", tr("Paste"));
           action->setText(actionText);
       }
       else if (actionText.contains("Delete"))
       {
           actionText.replace("Delete", tr("Delete"));
           action->setText(actionText);
       }
       else if (actionText.contains("Select All"))
       {
           actionText.replace("Select All", tr("Select All"));
           action->setText(actionText);
       }
    }

    menu->exec(e->globalPos());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(argv)
    translator = QtCore.QTranslator()
    translator.load("translations/qt_zh_CN.qm")
    app.installTranslator(translator)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Try not to just dump code, and elaborate on your answer: why does this work? Why is this the better solution?